# What is the best way to upload large files with many users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, file-upload

I have a website that I rent a private Server for it. It's a registration website in which users have to upload their photos or documents in order to register.

The problem is that in the same time 100 users are uploading 10MB photos on it and it causes some issues and finally none of them can upload their photo  and register. I doubt that its depends on the server bandwidths and think that there should be another reason and a solution for this.

Now I limit the upload size to 4MB (in web.config) and it seems to work without any problem while in the near future I have to unlimit the size because my website is going to pass Beta to final.

What's the best solution for this?

---

**Update :** Actually the website provided for a festival where photographers have to upload their Original photos (which taken with DSLRs and most of them have 10MB photos)

Also as I told I don't think that this is related to server because I don't have new users, but my current users ( or few new ones) are uploading their photos in ordr to submit their photos to festival

Web farm would be last option for me

Comment: a 10MB photo? Are you serious? a 250kb photo should be more than sufficient

Comment: @Nasser, appears like server is unable to handle the i/o load. What is the estimate for user traffic? how many new users can be there per day uploading their photos? Perhaps, u may not encounter 100 **concurrent** new users! Otherwise, only option is to scale the web server (i.e. use web farms or scale up the web server).

Comment: @jcolebrand: It could be a website for photographers for all we know...

Comment: @AlexR. not for a profile photo (which this specifically says it is) ~ Additionally, one server choking on 200 uploads ... that sounds like something else is going on here.

Comment: @everyone, I can provide the code if it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/dark_side_of_file_uploads) nice article to understand the limitations with default asp.net file uploader.

Changing the **maxRequestLength** might not be sufficient but it may be required to increase the **executionTimeout** as well. Try those options.

If you still fail, you might want to use a third party fileupload component .

Telerik has a nice component - http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx

File uploader ( i've used sometime back and it was pretty good in the multi user enviornements) - http://www.mediachase.com/fuploader/overview.aspx

Both the above are commercial versions and here is a free one from codeplex. (havent tried this though)  - http://neatupload.codeplex.com/